# Javascript's new Date(datestring) inconsistent

Tags: javascript

I have an input `datetime-local`

I pick the date `2019-11-05T10:01` and construct a new date with this string: `new Date(datestring)`

In **Chrome** I get this:

`Tue Nov 05 2019 10:01:00 GMT+0100 (Mitteleuropäische Normalzeit)`

In **iOS** I get this:

`Tue Nov 05 2019 11:01:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`

Can you tell my why there is an 1 hour difference??

Comment: Is `2019-11-05T10:01` supposed to be local time or utc time? if it is the utc time add a `z` at the end like so : `2019-11-05T10:01z`

Comment: For IOS you need to spread the values ex: 
new Date(year, monthIndex [, day [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, milliseconds]]]]]);

Comment: the original string is local time not utc

Comment: @matthias Have you ensured that both machines have the same datetime settings? If they have different times then the input will be read differently.

Comment: yes, the have the same settings. Running on the same machine